# Single quotes getting removed from dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

If I run this:

```
echo 'export POD_IP=$(hostname -I|cut -f1 -d ' ')' >> /home/myuser/.bash_profile
```

I end up with this in the .bash_file

```
export POD_IP=$(hostname -I|cut -f1 -d  )
```

It removes the two single quote towards the end of the line

What do I need to do to keep the two single quotes please?

I've had no luck so far :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the way the shell interprets single and double quotes. To keep the single quotes in the output, you need to escape them.

Here's how you can modify your echo command to include the single quotes:

```
echo 'export POD_IP=$(hostname -I|cut -f1 -d '\'' '\'' )' >> /home/myuser/.bash_profile
```